# UIImage picker changes image size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an application in which I am scanning text from a picture. I am using OCR. Now the problem is my source image size is 3024*3024. I have copied the image into iPhone 6 Simulator in Xcode. Now when I uploaded the image using uiimagepicker controller the image was resized to 748*748 and its quality is not same.

When I tried to increase image size the image's quality is not the same.
What I need is image in its actual size and quality/resolution should not change.

Comment: Can you share the code in your `imagePickerController: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method? Are you using the `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` from the info dictionary?

Comment: here is the code
UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
and I think that could be a problem. Let me try your solution

Answer (score 0):

try this code to resize image

```
- (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)img scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;{

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );

[img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

UIImage* newImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImg;
}
```

and For the compression of images

```
NSData *dataForJPEGFile = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(theImage, 0.6);
```

Thanks

Comment: I am already using this but the problem is with image scaling the quality is compromised.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the qualityType property of your UIImagePickerController to `UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh`? The default is medium.

Comment: The qualityType property only applies to video.